# como puedo hacer un do while php

Tags: php, mysqli

Necesito un poco de soporte en lado de **php** 
estoy actualizado a **mysqli** ya que **xampp** ya no da soporte a mysql ahora da soporte a **MARIADB** y necesitaba actualizar los **do** y los **while**.

**Código:**

```
<?php 
    do{?> 

    } 
    while ($row_DatosPost = mysql_fetch_assoc($DatosPost));
?>
```

**Solucion**

```
<?php do {
/* primera vez*/echo "hola";  while ($row_DatosUser = mysqli_fetch_assoc($DatosUser));?>
```

Espero puedan aportar alguna idea que ayude a mi problema. Grcias

Comment: MariaDB es un fork de Mysql, por lo tanto el conector de Mysql debería de funcionar sin ningún problema, tengo mas de dos años trabajando con el conector de .net para Mysql en MariaDB. Lo del do-while funciona de la misma manera en que lo tienes, solo trata de quitar el ?> despues del do { http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.do.while.php

Comment: La solución la puedes marcar en la parte de abajo donde se encuentran las respuestas a tu pregunta, todo ésto para evitar confusiones en la problemática.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tal y como lo tienes debería funcionar

```
<?php
do {
    /* primera vez*/

} while ($row_DatosPost = mysql_fetch_assoc($DatosPost));
?>
```

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_fetch_assoc() in C:\xampp\htdocs\web\categorias.php:77 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\web\categorias.php on line 77

Comment: listo ya lo solucione gracias por su aporte mysqli_fetch_assoc

Comment: pon la respuesta para futuros lectores con el mismo problema

Answer (score 1):

Con `msqli` seria algo asi:

```
$mysql = conectarBD(); //coneccion a la bd
    $sql="SELECT * FROM tabla";
    $resultado = $mysql->query($sql);
    while ($imprime=$resultado->fetch_assoc()) {        
     echo $imprime["nombre"];
    }
```